# Preloading Images & [object HTMLImageElement]

Tags: jquery, image, preload

I'm trying to create preloader, but when I run this, console displays this:

> Loaded **[object HTMLImageElement]** of 5

from this line of code

```
console.log('Loaded ' + images[i] + ' of ' + images.length);
```

But Ideally I want it to display:

> "Loaded 1 of 5"

How can I fix this? I just want to create this as a callback so I know when all images in a certain panel has loaded.

```
$(panel).each(function(){

    // Find Panel
        var panelId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log('Loading ' + panelId);  

    // Find Images
        var images = $(this).find('img');
        var path = images.attr('src');
        console.log('Total of ' + images.length + ' Images');

    // Preload Images
        for( i= 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {

            images[i] = new Image();
            images[i].src = path;
            images[i].onload = function(){
                console.log('Loaded ' + images[i] + ' of ' + images.length);
            };

        }

    // End

});
```

Also - How could I modify my `each()` loop, to check each a panel, after the previous panel has finished checking?

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario From the for loop? I thought the [i] variable needed to be pulled from the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, I'll remove my comment.

Comment: You can't really use the `i` anyway since the order that the images load isn't guaranteed. If you used `i`, you may get `1,3,2,4,5` depending on the size of each image. also, in your code above you always get the same `images[i]`, the last one.

Comment: @KevinB Makes sense, I'm not too bothered which order it loads them in, as long as I know which ones have loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare a counter and increment it as you go:

```
$(panel).each(function(){
        var loaded = 0; // <== The counter

    // Find Panel
        var panelId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log('Loading ' + panelId);  

    // Find Images
        var images = $(this).find('img');
        var path = images.attr('src');
        console.log('Total of ' + images.length + ' Images');

    // Preload Images
        for( i= 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {

            images[i] = new Image();
            images[i].src = path;
            images[i].onload = function(){
                ++loaded;
                console.log('Loaded ' + loaded + ' of ' + images.length);
            };

        }

    // End

});
```

**Don't** use `i`, as at least one commenter suggested (and as I suggested before reading your code more carefully). `i` will always be `images.length` by the time the load callback is done.

Another change you need to make is to set the `onload` callback **before** setting `src`, so instead of:

```
// PROBLEM, sets up a race condition
images[i].src = path;
images[i].onload = function(){
    // ...
};
```

do this:

```
images[i].onload = function(){
    // ...
};
images[i].src = path;
```

JavaScript on web browsers is single-threaded (barring the use of web workers), but *the web browser is not*. It can easily check its cache and see that it has the image and run its code to trigger the `load` handlers between the line setting `src` and the line setting `onload`. It will queue up the handlers to be run the next time the JavaScript engine is available, but if your handler isn't there to get queued, it won't get queued, and you never get the `load` event callback.

Comment: This works, but not inside the panel.each loop. It continues the counter on to the next panel

Loaded 1 of 5 
Loaded 2 of 5 
Loaded 3 of 5 
Loaded 4 of 5 
Loaded 5 of 5 
Loaded 6 of 1

Comment: @JasonMayo: Sorry, misread where the images were coming from. You just need to move the `var loaded = 0;` line *into* the iteration callback (answer updated).

Comment: @t-j-crowder Wicked, that works. All makes sense what you've said. Any idea how I can make the each loop for my panels, load the next panel after ALL images have loaded in the previous panel?

This solution is to overcome the problem I had with my previous question which you answered. I decided to not load content from external files.

Comment: @JasonMayo: It's fundamentally the mechanism I showed you before. Instead of doing the `each` loop, have an index for the panel you're loading, and call your function to load the panel and wait for its images. Once `loaded` equals `images.length`, increment the panel index and (if you have any further panels) have the function call itself again.

Comment: @t-j-crowder Got'cha! Will have a bash at that now.