# I use JavaScript FIleReader read a pic , but I can't get the pic 's infomation .

Tags: javascript, image, filereader

I can't get the picture's infomation use code below . I don't know why .

```
var f = obj.files[0];
var imageType = /image.*/;
if (f.type.match(imageType)) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(e) {
        var value = r.result;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = value;
        alert(img.width+" "+img.height);
    }
    r.readAsDataURL(f);
} else {
    alert("read error");
}
```

I got the browser alert is `0 0` , anyone , thanks .

Comment: Image is not loaded instantly.

Comment: You're getting the width and height before the image is loaded. Use `onload`. [Also look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205874/preloading-images-object-htmlimageelement).

Comment: should I sleep a while for waiting the browser read the picture ?

Comment: @zh18: No, you shouldn't sleep a while, you should just wait that the browser has fully loaded the picture and **then** do what you need. h2oooooo's comment is absolutely enough for such a question, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205874/preloading-images-object-htmlimageelement) really help me .

Just write the callback function before you give the path to image.src , like this .

`image.onload = function(){
    // ...
 };
 image.src = path;`